# Eliminar propiedad de objeto JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como ejemplo, podemos plantear un objeto de la siguiente manera:

```
var myObject = {
    "Event": "Prueba",
    "method": "post",
    "url": "http://"
};
```

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de eliminar la propiedad `url` para terminar con un nuevo objeto `myObject`?, ejemplo:

```
var myObject = {
    "Event": "Prueba",
    "method": "post"
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var myObject = {
    "Event": "Prueba",
    "method": "post",
    "url": "http://"
};

delete myObject.url;
// o puedes usar
//delete myObject['url'];
console.log('url property delete', myObject);
```

Puedes usar el operador [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete).

Te de deje dos formas, si encuentras mas la compartes.

```
var myObject = {
"Event": "Prueba",
"method": "post",
"url": "http://" };

delete myObject.url;
// o puedes usar
//delete myObject['url'];
console.log('url property delete', myObject);
```

> [Ejemplo en Codepen](https://codepen.io/clenondavis/pen/rZeRqz?editors=1111)

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Con [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/delete), por ejemplo:

```js
var myObject = {
    "Event": "Prueba",
    "method": "post",
    "url": "http://"
};

// imprime el objeto con el atributo "url"
console.log(myObject);

// elimino el atributo
delete myObject.url;

// imprime el objeto sin el atributo "url"
console.log(myObject);
```